# SVN Switch Command - Tortoise SVN Error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I created a branch on the server (couldn't do it from my dev machine, same error) When I try to switch the working copy to the new branch, I get "Unreadable path encountered; access denied".

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: hmmm... I'm thinking config error.  what's your authorization configuration like?

Comment: What does the path look like? Are you using [http, svn+ssh](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.overview.html) or some other protocol?

Comment: Show us the exact error message and what's logged to SVN server's log (if any exists).